# Cordova | Get live stream from microphone on iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, dialogflow-es

I am trying to build a voice calendar app that needs to use live stream from the microphone for speech recognition.

So you have a button that starts listening to the microphone and stops automatically when the user stops speaking.

I have already explored Cordova Media API that allows me to record the data to a wav file. This works but makes the process very slow since I need to wait for the recording to be finished.

I used the https://api.ai as a starting point to build the 1st version of the app which works quite well. It took care of all the "listening" part!

Next phase for me is to integrate with a few different speech recognition APIs.

The major issue for me has been the lack of native development skills, so are there any cordova plugins that can help me do this?

**Update 1 - 1st April 2016**

Found this https://subvisual.co/blog/posts/39-tutorial-html-audio-capture-streaming-to-node-js-no-browser-extensions
Will be trying to implement this in cordova through webrtc.

---

**Update 2 - 1st April 2016**

Installed https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc to utilize webrtc

---

**Update 3 - 2nd April 2016**

Stuck at `AudioContext.createMediaStreamSource` is not a function on iOS!
[AudioContext.createMediaStreamSource alternative for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33608544/audiocontext-createmediastreamsource-alternative-for-ios)

---

**Update 4 - 6th April 2016**

Going Native - Time to learn iOS Development!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry to hear that you gave up on Cordova, but if you still are interested: I've created a cordova plugin for iOS and Android, that enables you to capture microphone data and forward it to the web layer of your application. You can either rely on the Web Audio API to handle the incoming sound, or use any other way to encode and save the raw sound data:

https://github.com/edimuj/cordova-plugin-audioinput

Example usage:

```
function onAudioInput( evt ) {
  // 'evt.data' is an integer array containing raw audio data
  console.log( "Audio data received: " + evt.data.length + " samples" );

  // ... do something with the evt.data array ...
}

// Listen to audioinput events
window.addEventListener( "audioinput", onAudioInput, false );

// Start capturing audio from the microphone
audioinput.start();
```

Comment: Thank you. This is just StackOverflow etiquette since links can often become outdated/unusable if the URL changes, so keep that in mind for future posts

Comment: @EdinMujkanovic Thanks for the answer. I'll be revisiting the cordova app for the audio input soon and this should be really helpful for that :)

Comment: @Edin how can i process evt.data to detect silence? thanks

Comment: Does it record the mic from the iPhone or the Android smartphone? Or does it record from the web browser only on Desktop?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer: the plugin in question is available for iOS and Android and the web browser.